# Can't publish a Google Script as a Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

When I try to publish a google script, it keeps loading with a message that says "getting data" or something like that but in spanish.
And it never ends, it keeps saying that.

I have trying cleaning the cache and cookies, also try with private browsing

It never ends loading, then it won't let me publish it.
How can I publish the script?

[This is an image of the message that appears in spanish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwDT4.png)
It says Deploy as a web app and below, getting data.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not a temporary server problem, it should be an error message not displayed. When the modal appears try to open the network tab of browser inspector and open the underlying *sharingService* request. The JSON response could contain a message like this or a little different:

*Web apps can be enabled or disabled only by the script owner*